# error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have error in here :  `image:NetworkImage(cars.docs[i].data()["imagePro"]`  do you know how to fix this error? I want to get profile picture from firebase to show on page, I tried this :`image:NetworkImage(cars.docs[i].data()["imagePro"] ?? ''`  but it doesn't work!!!
part of the code:

```
Map<String , dynamic> carData = {
                    'imagePro': userImageUrl,
                    };

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Widget showCarsList(){
      if (cars != null){
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: cars.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context , i){
              return Card(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      leading: GestureDetector(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: NetworkImage(cars.docs[i].data()["imagePro"],),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
          },
        );
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the structure of your database?

Comment: And maybe showing us the error message/code would be useful too!

Comment: check the duplicate